# Finding a function $g$ which is analytic on the region $E=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| >1 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a function $g$ which is analytic on the region $E=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| >1 \}$ and maps $E$ one-to-one onto $H= \{ w \in \mathbb{C}: Re w<0 \}$.

My approach:

The region $E=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| >1 \}$ maps to the unit disk by a function $f_1(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

The unit disk maps to the upper half plane by a function $f_2(z)=\frac{-i(z+1)}{z-1}$

But since we don't want the upper half plane, we want the left half plane, we perform a rotation of $e^{-i\alpha }$ to $f_2(z)$ where $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore, $e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}}=-i$. Therefore, $f_2(z)=\frac{-i((-iz)+1)}{(-iz)-1}=\frac{-z-i}{-iz-1}$

Finally, since we want a map from $E$ to $H$,we compose $$f(z)=f_2(f_1(z))$$

My questions are:

1) Is this the right approach?

2) Is it more convinent to just use cross ratios?

Comment: Minor complaint: the unit *circle* is $|z|=1$|. The unit *disk* is $|z|<1$.

Comment: Thank you. Proper vocab matters on this. Do I have the right approach? I'm skeptical as to the rotation. Not sure if that's the way to rotate.

Comment: Luckily for you this isn't too tough to check! Note that $f(z) = \frac{iz+1}{z+i}$. Then $f(2i)=\frac{-1}{3i} = 1/3 i$; but $|2i|>1$, and $\Re(1/3i) \not\le 0$.

Comment: (Should read $\nless$, oops)

Comment: Real part of $\frac{1}{3i}$ is equal to $0$ right? So it works?

Comment: No, we want the real part to be negative - that's what the left half-plane is. (I think your issue is going to be your rotation.)

Comment: definitely. How do I fix that?

Comment: Instead of *substituting* $iz$ for $z$, you should multiply the whole expression by $z$. (When going from your first $f_2$ to your second $f_2$.)

Comment: $f_2(z)=\frac{(-i)[-i(z+1)]}{z-1}$?

Comment: nope. doesn't work either

Comment: I just realized there isn't a map like the one you're looking for. Can you check the statement of the problem again?

Comment: I think I can find one using cross ratios I'm doing it right now

Comment: No, there literally isn't such a map, unless you include the point at infinity in $|z|>1$.

Comment: Probably a typo then. I'll check with my professor. Thank you

Comment: @Mike they probably meant to put a $>$ symbol then this would be so much easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We aim to prove that there is no such map. A bijective holomorphic map between open subsets of the complex plane has a holomorphic inverse (see for example theorem 10.33 in Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis"). Holomorphic maps are continuous; so this means if there existed a bijective holomorphic map from $E=\{z \in \Bbb C : |z| > 1\}$ to the left half-plane, we would have a [homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) between these two spaces. But the left half-plane is [simply connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) while $E$ is not. Since simple connectedness is preserved by homeomorphisms, this is a contradiction.

Comment: So the map cannot be unique?

Comment: @User69127 No, the map you want cannot even *exist*. (If you meant that it cannot be bijective, yes, that is correct.)

Comment: Must be a typo then. Will come back to notify you. Awesome job man!

Comment: @User69127 Glad to help - makes sense that it's a typo; I don't think they would expect you to be able to come up with this argument.